# Generate JSON Data in Expandable tableView cell in Swift

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swift

I am using Swift for an iOS app. I need something exactly like this https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jkexpandtableview. In my case the data for each cell will be different and loaded from JSON. The library is written in Objective C. I need something similar that is written with Swift

Comment: You can run objc code in swift (many people seem to miss this) by bridging it.

Comment: Do I have to do it for each objective c file ?

Answer (score 1):

How to add a bridging header in Swift:

File > New > File (Command + N)

Select Objective-C file.

Name it whatever you want.

Select directory to create file.

A popup will appear giving you the option to create an Objective-C bridging header. Select "Yes".

Now you have two files, one .m file, and another .h file. They will run in your swift project.

Comment: Do I have to do it for each objective c file ?

Comment: Yes. You do have to do it each time you create a new file.

Answer (score 0):

To add a bridging file i usually do it manually (because I dont trust xcode anymore) by adding a new .h file and you can call it what you want but recommended something with bridger or bridging-header in it.

Then add the file path inside build settings in "Objective-C Bridging Header"

[image]

Then you are set to go and every objc files you add to your project you simply import the .h files you want:

```
// Inside Your Bridger.h

#import "Filename1.h"
#import "Filename2.h"
#import "Filename3.h"
```

And then you can use the classes inside those files just like if they were written in Swift.